# Error when using align ''Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.47 \end{align}''

Tags: errors, equations, align

I get

> "Missing } inserted.   } l.47 \end{align}''

when I'm using the `align` function to align multiple equations. The code works if I remove `\begin{align}...\end{align}` and the `&` symbols before the equals.

This is the section of code with an error.

[image: That is the section of code that has a problem]

This is what I get when I remove the `\begin{align}...\end{align}` and the `&` before the equals.

[image: When i remove \begin{align} and \end{align}]

What I wanna do is aligning all the equals one over another?

Also, I'm new to LaTeX, if i'm doing some general errors or do something wrong I'm open to receiving comments on that.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `align` automatically puts you into math mode, so the `$` signs are not only unnecessary, but likely to get you in trouble.  also, rather than a screen shot of the input, you can just cut-and-paste into the edit window,, then highlight the block with a mouse-over, and click on the `{}` above the edit window to indicate that this is code.  and welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` are not needed here since the `align` environment is in math mode. Give this a shot.

```
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{2^{3/4}}(1+y)dydx &= \int_{-1}^{1}\Big[\frac{y}{2^{3/4}}+\frac{y^{2}}{2^{7/4}}\Big]_{0}^{2}dx\\
&= \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2}{2^{3/4}}+\frac{4}{2^{7/4}}dx\\
&= \Big[\frac{2x}{2^{3/4}}+\frac{4x}{2^{7/4}}\Big]_{-1}^{1}\\
&= \frac{2}{2^{3/4}}+\frac{4}{2^{7/4}}-\Big(\frac{-2}{2^{3/4}}-\frac{4}{2^{7/4}}\Big)\\
&= 4\sqrt[4]{2}
\end{align}
```

[image]

If you do not want each line to be numbered, simply use `align*` instead of `align`.

Hope this helps!